# What is the proper configuration for Django 1.5 static files on Windows?

Tags: django, file, url, static, root

I'm using Django 1.5
And I'm having problems with static files.

statiic settings :

```
STATIC_ROOT =''
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = ('C:/Python33/Django-1.5/django/bin/pollbooth/templates/files/static',)
```

I have included django.contrib.staticfiles in INSTALLED APPS

After `manage.py runserver` , when i open localhost or 127.0.0.1:8000, my home page loads all the static files..
But when I click on another link, that page does not load the static file.

You can see the command box image from this link
http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8238/8599256147_aa6875d657_b.jpg

Can you tell me where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How are you loading static files in your templates? I guess your directory structure might be wrong.

```
/project_root/
manage.py
    /project/
        /static/
            /css/
            /js/
            /img/
        /media/
        settings.py
        urls.py
    /app/
        /static/
            /app/ <-- important when using app specific static files
                /css/
                /js/
                /img/
```

Answer (score 4):

Your static url is `/static/`. The about page looks for static files at `/about/static`, which will of course, not be found. Change the static reference in your about page.

Refer to static files like the examples given below, in your templates:

```
{{ STATIC_URL }}js/application.js
{{ STATIC_URL }}css/app.css
{{ STATIC_URL }}appname/js/app.js
```

Answer (score 2):

In your templates, change your links to:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ STATIC_URL }}js/bootstrap.min.js" />
```

Right now you probably have the following (notice a missing slash before `static/`):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="static/js/bootstrap.min.js" />
```